# OneSignal multiple notification

Tags: onesignal

I have some problem with web push notification. I'm able to send the notification, but, when I send two notification and the first is still visible on the screen, the second overwrite the first one. Is it possible to show 2 notifications at same time?

I find some information on official GitHub of OneSignal, but can't figure it out. Please help
[link to GitHub](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/pull/211/commits/aaa4a772b5f7c290fed6c5e70ea7e407fce0c8d0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this.

Here, I stopped .inFocusDisplaying so that notifications don't pop up when I am in my app.

.inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)

And here, I send the notification payload to a . You could collect payloads and displays them all at once, or say, when you have accumulated 2.

var notificationReceivedCallback = function (jsonData) {
            $("#message").html(jsonData.payload.body);  //display message received from onesignal
        };

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Enable to debug issues.
    // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

    var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    var notificationReceivedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        $("#message").html(jsonData.payload.body);  //display message received from onesignal
    };

    window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit("your app id")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .handleNotificationReceived(notificationReceivedCallback)
        .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
        .endInit();

}, false);
```